# Is it posssible Browser Automation Studio auto fill?

Tags: browser-automation

We have a database which type is Json file.
We need to read data from Json file to add this file in our web site
(Our web site view like as in the below picture).
Is it posssible to this process with BAS(Browser Automation Studio)?
Our data is dynamic.

[image: Our web site view like as in the below picture]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  You can use "type text"

Comment: It also has json module so you can parse json content